# Permutations between 2 lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

From 2 list i would like to know an optimal way in Python to do a sort of "indexed permutation".
This is how this would look like :

input :

```
list2 = [3,4,5]
list1 = [0,1,2]
```

output

```
[[0,1,2], [0,1,5], [0,4,2], [3,1,2],
      [3,4,5], [3,4,2], [3,1,5], [0,4,5],
]
```

So each element of the lists remains in the same index.

Comment: The logic is not immediately obvious. Please specify the logic in your question. If it is what I suspect it is, then `[0, 4, 3]` is a typo and should be `[0, 4, 2]`

Comment: Indeed it's [0,4,2]

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: I can't understand at all. What exactly is being permuted? What is the rule that tells you how to get the output from the input? It seems like what you **actually** want is all of the lists, where the first value is either `0` or `3` (i.e. the first values from the inputs), the second value is `1` or `4` and the last is `2` or `5`. In that case, it has **nothing to do with** permutations. You are looking for a **cartesian product**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want two variables: `list_to_pick`, which can vary in `range(number_of_lists)`, and `index_to_swap` which can vary in the `range(-1, len(list1))`. Then, you want the *product* of these two ranges to decide which list to pick, and which item to swap. When `index_to_swap` is `-1`, we won't swap any items

```
import itertools

source = [list1, list2]

result = []

for list_to_pick, index_to_swap in itertools.product(range(len(source)), range(-1, len(source[0])):
    # Make a copy so we don't mess up the original list
    selected_list = source[list_to_pick].copy() 

    # There are only two lists, so the other list is at index abs(list_to_pick - 1)
    other_list = source[abs(list_to_pick - 1)]

    # We swap only if index_to_swap >= 0
    if index_to_swap >= 0:
        selected_list[index_to_swap] = other_list[index_to_swap] 

    result.append(selected_list)
```

Which gives:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [0, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 5],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [0, 4, 5],
 [3, 1, 5],
 [3, 4, 2]]
```

The order is not the same as your required list, but all the "permutations" are there. If you want the same order as in your question, you will have to define the second argument to `itertools.product` as:

```
swap_indices = [-1] + list(range(len(source[0])-1, -2, -1))
```